# How to map discrete colours in a Plotly Sunburst chart in r

Tags: colors, plotly, r-plotly, sunburst-diagram

I am very new to using plotly in rstudio and have come up against a problem with mapping discrete colours (stored as hex codes in the field `color`) to each of the slices in my `ids` field.

I have included my code below:

```
df %>%
  plot_ly(
     color = I("black"),
     marker = list(colors = ~color)) %>% 
  add_trace(ids = df$ids, 
            labels = df$labels, 
            parents = df$parents,
            type = 'sunburst',
            maxdepth = -1,
            domain = list(column = 0)) %>%
  layout(sunburstcolorway = df$color)
```

This is the resulting sunburst diagram I get using this code, which is obviously not ideal:

[image: This is the sunburst diagram I get using my code above, obviously not ideal]

Ideally the first four levels would have the same colour, and then different hex colour codes are used for slices that are labelled "Poor","Moderate","GwC" or "Good".

A csv file of my data frame used above is [available here](https://actgov.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/fb87570baf264be6a24e72efe7ba8132/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to nut out how to map my colour field to the background colours on the sunburst chart - have updated the code in original post. All that was required was to insert the following code segment:

```
plot_ly(
    marker = list(colors = ~color))
```

Below is the output chart:
[image]